# How can I run two instances of Apache 2 on two different ports on the same machine?

Tags: apache-http-server

Is this just a configuration change or also requires copying apache files/directories?

Answer (score 3):

Create a new httpd.conf for the new server, you're going to need to change ServerRoot, PIDFile, and Port at a minimum. Then start apache with the -f option pointing to the new config file.